# How do I load test large UPSs?

Tags: power-supply, power, ups, power-consumption, stress-test

I'm currently the only hardware repair person at my work and I've been left with a pile of UPSs that need to be fixed and tested. As it is I've been load testing the smaller (250-500 watt) units using some high wattage incandescent light bulbs to ensure that they still work up to around their maximum rated output.

However I also have a few 1KW and 2KW rack mount UPSs to fix and test. I could use the same method with those but that is a blinding amount of lights and frankly more of a fire hazard than I'm really comfortable with. I also want to do a more accurate test with those as they are going to be used for much more critical systems.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get a fairly accurate high load on these things without buying a $2000 variable load tester or accidentally burning down my workplace?

Comment: You could use a radiant or convection heater of a suitable rating. You can use a high-current ammeter to check that the rated power is being delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting problem!

Just some wild guesses: For a period of some minutes you could use an array of vacuum cleaners, for a shorter period some water boilers (electric kettle) - they have an safe auto-shutoff feature, and you can re-arm them by replacing the water. Or you could improvise a rock concert using a large amplifier. I'm afraid neither variant is accurate... in any case, you will have to have to employ an amperemeter. At least the amplifier method will give you a variable load ;)

But at last, any load will generate heat, and heat only.

Comment: I love the suggestions and the amplifier one actually gave me an idea that may work better. I have a couple of 1kw dc electric motors laying around. I could build a variable load test rig with those and load those down with an old vehicle torque converter or a custom built magnetic load. That way most of the energy is transmitted into motion rather than heat and I can have an easily adjustable power draw. Of course that's more of a hobby project so for the time being I am going to be stuck with light bulbs.

Comment: ...stationary training bikes with eddy-current brakes :)